# Android JSON encoding charset troubles

Tags: android, json, encoding

I have a problem with my android app `JSON` encoding. No matter what I do it outputs slash sign `/` as `\/`. I've looked some problems about this but I haven't got them to work.
Here's my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aaa);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT &gt; 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click

            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();

            Toast.makeText(MainTest.this, "button was pressed",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("id", randomUUIDString);
                json.put("photoUrl", "https://mysite.com/2011/10/image.jpg");
                postData(json);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}


public void postData(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_content);
        List&lt;NameValuePair&gt; nvp = new ArrayList&lt;NameValuePair&gt;();
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json.toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.i("TEST", json.toString(1));

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This prompts as

```
{
    "photoUrl": "https:\/\/mysite.com\/2011\/10\/image.jpg",
    "id": "7b34aa16-3c80-40b3-b12b-6decdd38fabc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the slashes.

`json.put("photoUrl", "https:\//mysite.com\/2011\/10\/image.jpg")`

Also notice that because you have no "\" in your original string you can easily replace "\" with ""
using `str.replace("\", "")`;

if you are using `Gson` then try:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()..disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

then hopefully gson will not escape your html

Comment: Can you do this automatically somehow? Does GSON help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's JSON option. Allowing `\/` helps when embedding JSON in a  tag, which doesn't allow `</` inside strings, like Seb points out.

In Javascript, the extra backslash is dropped, so:

```
console.log("AC\/DC"); // logs AC/DC
```

you can prevent it by using `\` before each `/`, like

```
json.put("photoUrl", "https:\//mysite.com\/2011\/10\/image.jpg")
```